# How to show kde panel at all monitors?

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde, panel, kde5

I have kubuntu 18.04 on my laptop.  And I use additional 2 monitors.
The default kubuntu panel only shows up at primary monitor.
For now I just created new panel, but they are different.
And I should to configure each of them.
How can I make it shows at all monitors? If its possible...

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can figure out via trial and error how to to edit these two files:

- `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`
- `~/.config/plasmashellrc`

And with that knowledge you can copy changes from one panel (and its children objects) to the other panel and vice versa. You can also then work that into a script to sync the panels with a single click.

You need one panel per screen you will connect. The only difference between the panels being their `lastScreen=0`. You can find your history of connected screens (and their index) at the end of the `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc` file at the `[ScreenConnectors]` section.

Sadly I didn't have the time to figure out the details here myself (feel free to change this answer). If you open the file with Kate and then add or change a panel it should offer to show you a diff with all the changes ("View Difference"). From there you can easily deduce how it works.

Alternatively, instead of `kate` you can also rely on `git` and simply commit the changes for later comparison.